# How do I set the relative position of a button?

Tags: java, swing

Now I have a panel called panel1, and I would like to place a button on panel1, and set the position of the button as (30,30). How can I do this?

I tried this, but seems that it is not the right way:(

```
     int x = panel1.getX();
     int y = panel2.getY();
     button.setLocation(x+30,y+30);
```

Thanks a lot, the layout manager seems to be a good choice, but here is my problem, I need to generate many buttons dynamically on the panel, and the button size is also different. So which layout manager shall I use? According to the tutorial, it seems that there is no such layout manager....A key problem is I don't want the buttons to look like they are organized in grid, for example, button1 at (20,20) size  15, and button 2 at (40,70) size 20, button 3 at (150,40) size 5.....

Comment: Folks will tell you to use the null layout, but I'm going to say, no, don't do this. The best answer is instead to let the layout managers do the positioning for you. You would gain much by studying the tutorial that covers this subject which  you can find here: [Laying out Components in a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/).

Comment: Also, if you want to give your JPanel a 30 point size border where components can't be added, look into giving the JPanel an `EmptyBorder(30, 30, 30, 30)`.

Comment: When you use `null` Layout, you have to take care for everything. It leads to more problems, than it solves. For example, your Application will look differently on different `LnF` and `Operating System`. Moreover in absolute positioning, you have to use `button.setSize(50, 30);` or another good alternative over `setLocation(...) and setSize(...)`                      is simply the use of             [setBounds(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds(int, int, int, int))

Comment: Thanks a lot, my problem is that I want the buttons to be scattered in the panel, not ordered in grid. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If scattered randomly, then you may have no choice but to use a null layout. If scattered, but non-randomly, then post a picture(s) of your GUI to get us a better handle on just what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the buttons to be scattered in the panel.

It's tempting to use an [absolute layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) for this, but you'd have to figure out a way to keep the buttons from overlapping or even hiding each other. It may be worth [*Creating a Custom Layout Manager*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/custom.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [form designer in NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html) and you can place buttons at arbitrary locations relative to each other in a GUI interface.  The builder uses the [GroupLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/groupExample.html) which you could do manually, but it's not recommended.